# How to print new line in string casts to ByteBuffer

Tags: java, newline, bytebuffer

I am using this piece of code:

```
String v="bla"; 
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();
ByteBuffer updated =encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(v+"albalb"));
```

The casting works fine, and I succeeded to print this `ByteBuffer` to a file that located in my cloud. Now, I want a new line after v is printed to the file. I've tried those things:

- `\r\n`
- `\n`
- `public static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");`

None of them worked for me. Anyone has idea?

Comment: What casting? There is no casting here. 'None of them worked' is not a problem description. Tried them how? Code? Result? Exception?

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to work fine for me.

```
    String v = "Hello"; 
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();
    ByteBuffer updated =encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(v+"\nWorld!"));
    String s = new String(updated.array(), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(s);
```

Maybe the error lies somewhere else?

EDIT with regards to comment.

```
    //Client side encoding.
    String inputString = "Hello\nWorld!"; 
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();
    byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(inputString.getBytes());
    ByteBuffer updated = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(new String(encodedBytes, charset)));
    String s = new String(updated.array(), charset);
    System.out.println("Base64 encoded string: " + s);

    //Server side decoding Base64
    CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
    CharBuffer decodedBytes = decoder.decode(updated);
    byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(decodedBytes.toString().getBytes());
    String decodedStr = new String(decoded, charset);
    System.out.println("Base64 decoded string: " + decodedStr);
```

Comment: I guess it's beacuse you print to the standart output..but when I write the buffer to a file which located in google app engine storage this doesn't work for me....

Comment: Maybe try encapsulating the data into Base64 before transferring it? This will avoid any issues with sanitization, perhaps one of the IO routines is doing input sanitization on the data and looking for newlines or something of that nature. It's worth a try. You can do Base64 using tools such as Apache Commons Codec - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html

Comment: can you write a piece of code implementing what you describe? I've tried some code I found uses Base64 but it printed me nonsense characters..

Comment: The caveat with this method is that you'll need to do extra computation once the data reaches the file on the cloud to decode the Base64. The idea for this is that since Base64 maps to a small character set it is less prone to being sanitized or anything of that nature. Honestly for a more complete solution to this you might need to provide more information regarding what exactly you're trying to accomplish.